# Xively Personal - was working but now data does not change

Tags: python, feed, xively

I'd appreciate any help that you might offer with debugging my AirPi based weather station that uploads data to my Xively Personal account. The station has been working and uploading for several months. I checked the Xively graphs and noticed that they had flat-lined. I checked the weather station and it was working as before, other than the status of the Python command that posts he data was coming back as failed.

I changed nothing so am really confused as to why something that worked flawlessly for months suddenly stopped and since that date has refused to work again.

Does anyone have any ideas what I might do to rectify this situation? Many thanks in advance for your attention.

Ian.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably failing as your weather station software is unable to verify the certificate provided by the server.

I experienced the same today, seems the last time the data had been successfully uploaded was about 2 weeks ago.

I'm using curl and for the time being, I solved it by using the "-k" switch (meaning curl will still allow to establish the connection).

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I rebuilt the code using the Xively Tutorial example as a base and it seems to be OK now, at least for the moment.

Comment: I experienced the same problem using a ruby client. My dirty workaround (in ruby)  was adding two lines like: require 'openssl'¥n OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE